# How to call JS-variables in the Razor-region?

Tags: html, jquery, razor

I have 4 dropdown boxes.

And if I change the country-dropbox the other dropboxes get filter based on the first one.

But how do you do that?

If I change the selected value, the process comes in the onChange-event. But I want to give back the selected values.

The Java-script:

```
<script>
   var countryId = '';
   function onChange() {
    
       countryId = $('#country option:selected').val();
       console.log(countryId);
   }
</script>
```

The Country-dropdown box

```
 <div class="row">
 @{
    Guid countryId = Guid.Empty;

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-lg-0 col-lg-3">
    <label for="checkin_date" class="font-weight-bold text-black">Select country:</label>
       <div class="field-icon-wrap">
           <select id="country" class="selectpicker dropdown" placeholder="Country" onchange="onChange();">
                                        @foreach (var country in Model.Countries)
                                        {
                                            if (countryId == Guid.Empty)
                                            {
                                                countryId = country.CountryId;
                                            }
                                            <option value="@(country.CountryId)" data-content="<img src='/images/@(country.Name).png'> @country.Name" >@country.Name</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

... and finally the foreach-loop in the City-dropdownbox:

```
<select id="city" ...>
    @foreach (var city in Model.Cities.Where(c => c.CountryId == countryId))
    {
       ...
       <option...
    }
```

Comment: You have various options: when you change country, make an ajax call to get the city list as html (PartialView) and replace it (probably easiest), or make an ajax call to get data/json and rebuild in the city list in js.  Alternatively, load your entire country-city pairings in to a js variable and rebuild in js.  Depends on data size which way to go.  Thirdly, use a component that already does this for you and you just need to provide it with an end point to get the data.

Comment: Now I call the Index-actionresult with parameters in the js-function.